# How to interpret the A records created by Kubernetes

Tags: dns, kubernetes

According to the Kubernetes documentation, services of the `ClusterIP` type will populate a `DNS` `A` type record with the following schema:

```
pod-ip-address.my-namespace.pod.cluster.local
```

I am having difficultly parsing this schema into a resolvable address for my application.

For example, suppose I have the following service:

```
subway-explorer-gmaps-proxy-service   ClusterIP   10.35.252.232   <none>   9000/TCP   19m
```

What will the corresponding DNS record be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application is in the same namespace as the service you wish to consume, you can use the servicename:

```
subway-explorer-gmaps-proxy-service
```

as the DNS name. Kube dns will resolve to the service IP.

If your application is not in the same namespace as that service, services get a DNS name of

```
$service.$namespace.svc.cluster.local
```

e.g. if the service was created in the default namespace, it will get

```
subway-explorer-gmaps-proxy-service.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Those names are resolvable anywhere in the cluster.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

Comment: Is a CLI attached to the cluster considered to be "inside" the cluster? E.g. will these DNS records be visible and queryable from the Google 
Cloud Shell, or do I have to `exec` into a pod to run the query. Asking for the sake of completeness, because I don't understand where the boundary between the CLI and the pods/containers is.

Comment: Sure- a cli is *not* considered to be inside the cluster. Those dns names are only going to be resolvable by the dns pods that live in the cluster. Those are the only dns servers that are wired into this service name->dns automation. Cloud shell is a web front end to a terminal session on a generic vm that is associated with your gcloud account, but is not kubernetes/gke-specific. The dns it uses will not be in-cluster dns. And the "connect" button in the gcloud console associated with a cluster only gives you kubectl credentials.